# Passing anonymous JS function to another function

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function, arrow-functions

First question/post. I am learning about ES6 arrow notation for anonymous functions and was playing around, trying to get the hang of it. Does anyone know why this is logging as false?

```
const myFunc = () => 'x';
function yourFunc(value) { 
  console.log(value == 'x');
  return;
};
yourFunc(myFunc);
//false
```

Thanks!

Comment: `value == 'x'` should be `value() == 'x'` - you're receiving a function but not executing it.

Comment: `value` is the function you passed. That function is not `== 'x'`. You need to invoke it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, because `myFunc` is a function (the fact it is an arrow function does not matter), so you're checking the equality between a function and a string

To correctly check, you need this

```js
console.log(value() == 'x');
```